# Azure Stream Analytics Test Query Editor not matching final output in ComosDB and Blob

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I have created a Stream Analytics job and using the portal I have validated that the query produces the correct output. The problem is when I start the Stream Analytics Job the output sent to CosmosDB is a completely different and unexpected outcome.

This is the basic query, it uses some aggregation functions with a SlidingWindow:

```
SELECT src.DeviceID, System.Timestamp as Time, 
AVG(src.Value) as [AvgValue],
MIN(src.Value) as [MinValue],
MAX(src.Value) as [MaxValue],
COUNT(src.Value) as [SampleCount]
INTO [AvgOutputToCosmosDB]
FROM
[blob-stream-dev-testsample] as src TIMESTAMP BY src.DateTimeEndUTC
GROUP BY SlidingWindow(hour,1), src.DeviceID
```

I have tested the above alternating using WITH statements and writing to both CosmosDB and Blob storage, but both have the same incorrect output.

I am expecting 576 average logs for each Device ID. What I get is one average log per Device ID that uses 576 logs (SampleCount) to compute the average.

As stated, when using the Azure portal to test the query, it works. 576 rolling hour averages for each device.
I have:

1. Verified the output in the portal with test C# application computing the rolling average, all good.
2. Configured the CosmosDB collection to be unlimited and use a partition on the deviceid. I don't think it is CosmosDB because it happens in Blob storage.

In my tests I have manually uploaded the JSON file and also read the JSON file from blob storage - again portal worked fine.

Anyone seen this before? 
I am wondering if there is some kind of DateTime conversion issue with the locale used by the Stream Analytics Job?

**UPDATE**

I just tested the same query using an Event Hub topic as an input stream and it works in both the portal and when running the SA Job. There must be some kind of date time serialisation issue when the SA Job reads the JSON file from Blob storage.

Comment: Please check if there were any late or degraded events when using blob as input. If there weren't any, start with a select * to debug

Answer (score 0):

one difference between blob and the other input is the way we get the arrival time: for blob, the arrival time is read from [BlobLastModifiedUtcTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-inputs#stream-data-from-blob-storage). This means that if the difference between the application time (src.DateTimeEndUTC) and the arrival time (BlobLastModifiedUtcTime) is greater than the late arrival policy, it will be adjusted and all your events will be in the same time window. You can find more info related to this setting [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-out-of-order-and-late-events).

My suggestion would be to check your current late arrival policy, and make sure events arrive in the blob before the end of this policy.

BTW, are you streaming live data, or reprocessing historical data?

Let me know if you have any further question, will be happy to help.

Comment: I am not sure this is my issue as all items are read from the blob storage file. It looks like it is failing to recognise the datetime field to produce the aggregate GROUP BY.  Shouldn't TIMESTAMP BY override the default timestamp with the one in my message? The aggregate output all records, it just skipped the datetime field and started with the DeviceID. So why did it ignore the TIMESTAMP BY command?

Comment: Test data was on current day, no late arrival policy enabled. I think it would have skipped the files if this was an issue. All the data was in the output so it looks like a failure on TIMESTAMP BY. We do want to process historic data in the future, but we first need to solve the incompatibility issue with Stream Analytics and the AVRO format used by IoT/Event Hub.